# (C++) How do you generate a seven digit number, whose digits, when added together, equal to a multiple of seven?

Tags: c++, random

I know this sounds like a very specific question, but I am making a key generator for a program, and one part of the key has seven digits that need to be a multiple of seven when added together. How do you achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Generate a random 6-digit number then choose the number for the 7th digit that makes the algorithm work.

See any example of how to use std::rand for generating the random digits.

Comment: Would you really recommend `std::rand` when OP is making a key generator? We have much better options now with `<random>`

Comment: you are right about std::rand being easier, lol. I can generate the 6 digits and that is definitely a good start but what I can't figure out is how to make the seventh one to meet the criteria

Comment: @potato112 Well, you *know* the sum of the six pseudo-random digits and there's a multiple of 7 every seven numbers... Hint: consider the result of `sum % 7`.

Comment: It's not "easier to learn", it's "let's pretend there's nothing complicated and let it crash and burn". RNG is _hard_. Sampling is _hard_. You're contributing to a problem, not solving one. Furthermore, `<random>` is barely harder than `std::rand` and `std::srand`.

Comment: @PasserBy Well, I just did a google for C++ random. I found multiple examples showing how to use rand(). It takes a call to srand() to seed it (just copy and past it) and then a simple 1-line call to generate random numbers in a range. Tons of easy. I hit 5 different sites and not one talked about random. So I went to the docs on random instead. And for someone needing help at this level, no, random is not easier to use. It's freakishly confusing.

Comment: Again, `srand` and `rand` isn't "simple", it's pretending there's nothing wrong. It's the equivalent of walking down the road with a blindfold and claiming you don't see cars barreling straight at you. For random, instead of an implicit state, you now have an explicit state. Instead of rolling your own sampling, you use the library. It's "freakishly confusing" precisely because it is _hard_ to do rng, and claiming otherwise is just lying. The random API is already as simple as it could be, but no simpler.

Comment: @PasserBy Feel free to post your own answer. The person asking the question isn't ready for the complexity you're talking about. This is probably his first class in programming of any sort, based on the question. For the purpose of his homework assignment, I don't think the imperfections of rand() really matter. Do you really think he needs perfectly random numbers, or maybe pseudo-random is good enough?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have generated the 7 numbers for the key. You could than try a %7.
If the result is 0, than it mean that your number generated is a multiple of 7.
If the result is not 0, than you just have to regenerate another key or add 1 to the last number until modulo 7 (%7) equal 0.